# The Hamiltonian for the Pure Dephasing Model

Tags: quantum-optics, density-operator

I came across the hamiltonian for the pure dephasing model. It its:

> $$ \mathcal{\hat{H}} = \frac{\varepsilon}{2}\sigma_{z} + \sum_{k} \omega_{k} b_{k}^{\dagger} b_{k} + \sigma_{z} \sum_{k} (g_{k}^{*}b_{k} + g_{k}b_{k}^{\dagger}). $$

I'm not sure what motivates the hamiltonian. I'm sure it cam be derived, as is the case for the Jaynes Cummings Hamiltonian in Quantm Optics, but consider it a side point as as of now I'm not interested in it. I'm not sure what motivates that the system's coupling term is the pauli-Z matrix. The case for the population decay model is easy, where we have the rasiing and the lowering operators as the system's coupling term which simply raise or lowe the eigenstate of the system.

It'd be great if someone can explain the motivation behind the inclusion of such a coupling term in the context of dephasing -- which causes the off diagonal terms of the density matrix to lose coherence with time.

Comment: Let me check if I understand the question. You don't want to understand the physical derivation and context of this Hamiltonian, right? You just want to understand why, mathematically, a reservoir coupling proportional to $\sigma^z$ should lead to dephasing?

Comment: @MarkMitchison Well, I would want to understand the derivation. The reason I think it's superfluous for my purposes right now is that I worked on a summer project that involved studying this model. My undergrad supervisor gave me only a select few readings that ensured I didn't get bogged down in the detailed study of quantum optics/open quantum systems; rather, I learnt just enough to grapple the project (I don't intend to specialize in it anyway). For instance, I didn't derive the Hamiltonian, but I did go through the derivation of the system's density matrix for this case.

Comment: @MarkMitchison Now my supervisor wants me, as an undergrad, to give a talk to undergrads doing their senior year projects (this year) under his supervision about the work on the project. So I was mentally going over the details over the top of my head and I couldn't really recall the correct interpretation of this Hamiltonian; hence the question. I'd love to see a derivation, and I'm interested in it as well. But I guess for my purposes, a well presented explanation with mathematically written arguments would do as well. Keenly waiting a response. Feel free to cite resources for the derivation

Comment: @MarkMitchison P.S: I'm more of a derivation guy so please do list some resources. Perhaps I'll go through it if I choose to enroll in the course on quantum optics at my college, which is being offered next term. I'm sure we'll play around with the Jaynes-Cummings model, master equations and such models in more detail over there.

Answer (score 1):

I also came across this Hamiltonian in *[Skinner J L, Hsu D. Pure dephasing of a two-level system[J]. The Journal of Physical Chemistry, 1986, 90(21): 4931-4938.]*. So more details are discussed in the paper.

As for the motivation, I think it comes from two parts: 1. This Hamiltonian is simple(a minimum model with dephasing). 2. This Hamiltonian is physically possible, such as a two-level mechanical qubits whose energy shift is affected by the electromagnetic field by $H_{int} \propto \sigma_z \hat{E} \propto \sigma_z (a^\dagger + a)$.